# Event listener syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm reading code the following code:

```
$('body').on(
    "mouseup.tutorial, touchend.tutorial", 
    "#foo_id", 
    function () { /* doStuff */ });
```

I've never seen the syntax `mouseup.tutorial` or `touchend.tutorial`.  What does tutorial mean with this syntax?

Comment: Jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are qualifiers for the event names. They're mostly useful to make it easy to turn off particular event handlers without disturbing any unrelated handler(s) that may do unrelated things for the same events.

```
$('body').off("mouseup.tutorial");
```

That removes the handler added by your code, but leaves any other "mouseup" handlers alone.